# User input name to ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am writing a function to plot heat map for users. In the following example, it plots the change of grade over time for different gender.

However, this is a special case. "Gender" may have other name like "Class". 
I will let user input their specific name and then make ggplot have the right label for each axis.

How do I modify my function "`heatmap()`" based on what I need?

```
sampledata <- matrix(c(1:60,1:60,rep(0:1,each=60),sample(1:3,120,replace = T)),ncol=3)
colnames(sampledata) <- c("Time","Gender","Grade")
sampledata <- data.frame(sampledata)
heatmap=function(sampledata,Gender)
{
sampledata$Time <- factor(sampledata$Time)
sampledata$Grade <- factor(sampledata$Grade)
sampledata$Gender <- factor(sampledata$Gender)
color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#31a354","#2c7fb8", "#fcbfb8","#f03b20"))(length((levels(factor(sampledata$Grade)))))
ggplot(data = sampledata) + geom_tile( aes(x = Time, y = Gender, fill = Grade))+scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("10","20","30","40","50"))+scale_fill_manual(values =color_palette,labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6",">6"))+  theme_bw()+scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Female","Male"))
}
```

Comment: I think you need `aes_string`. Take a look at [this](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/rggplot2-tip-aes_string/) and [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177129/ggplot-and-loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is redefining the function using aes_string.
When the function is called, you need to pass it the name of the column
you want to use as a string.

```
heatmap=function(sampledata,y)
{
        sampledata$Time <- factor(sampledata$Time)
        sampledata$Grade <- factor(sampledata$Grade)
        sampledata$new_var <- factor(sampledata[,y])
        color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#31a354","#2c7fb8", "#fcbfb8","#f03b20"))(length((levels(factor(sampledata$Grade)))))
        ggplot(data = sampledata) + geom_tile( aes_string(x = "Time", y = "new_var", fill = "Grade"))+scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("10","20","30","40","50"))+scale_fill_manual(values =color_palette,labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6",">6"))+  theme_bw()+scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Female","Male")) + ylab(y)
}


# Below an example of how you call the newly defined function
heatmap(sampledata, "Gender")
```

Alternatively if you want to retain the quote free syntax, there is a slightly more complex solution:

```
heatmap=function(sampledata,y)
{
        arguments <- as.list(match.call())
        axis_label <- deparse(substitute(y))
        y = eval(arguments$y, sampledata)

        sampledata$Time <- factor(sampledata$Time)
        sampledata$Grade <- factor(sampledata$Grade)
        sampledata$y <- factor(y)
        color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#31a354","#2c7fb8", "#fcbfb8","#f03b20"))(length((levels(factor(sampledata$Grade)))))
        ggplot(data = sampledata) + geom_tile( aes(x = Time, y = y, fill = Grade))+scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("10","20","30","40","50"))+scale_fill_manual(values =color_palette,labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6",">6"))+  theme_bw()+scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Female","Male")) + ylab(axis_label)
}

# Below an example of how you call the newly defined function
heatmap(sampledata, Gender)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more question: in the second function, we are still using 'sampledata$Gender <- factor(sampledata$Gender)' which includes Gender. It does't work if I put 'sampledata$y <- factor(sampledata$y)'. How to solve this part?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change that part. I have edited both codes to make them more general. Now everything should work.

Comment: What if I want the label of y axis to be "Gender" instead of "new_var" and "y". (Gender is consistent with the user input, it can also be other names)

Comment: I have edited the code. Now the y label will have the same name as the variable you are passing to the function. In the first function you simply pass the variable name to *ylab*, since it is already a string. In the second there is a bit of extra code at the beginning to extract the name. I want more brownie points for this :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful. I have been searching around but couldn't figure it out. Now it works perfectly!